# How do I remove a stuck Mini CD from the SuperDrive on a Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive

I have a 2010 13" MacBook Pro that someone inserted one of those [Mini CD type discs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_CD) in to. The SuperDrive happily ingested the media but now refuses to spit it out. It does not show up as a mounted drive in Disk Utility.

I tried starting the machine up while holding down the Eject key and the SuperDrive makes a few clicks, but the media doesn't eject and the OS boots as normal.

There does not appear to be a hole on the outside of the Macbook where I might be able to insert a paperclip to push the media out.

Is there any way to get the disk out of the drive or am I destined for a Genius Bar appointment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not stick anything else in the slot. Really.

The inject / eject mechanism is keyed for a full sized disc and you don't want to wedge it in the wrong direction or retract that delicate part any further by fishing around inside the narrow slot. There is no eject button so you will need either luck or finesse and skill to get the CD out.

Power down the Mac and hold it firmly with the Apple logo facing you at chest height with the CD slot pointing to your lap. Gently rock and shake it to see if the CD is loose and encourage it to peek out the felt skirt that is inside the unibody enclosure.

Your Mac when powered off is very strong and you gently start it down and then quite forcefully yank it back up vertically. One or two shakes is all it takes to get the mini CD poking out just a bit. At that point, the felt will hold it and you can return the Mac to a level table and use tweezers or needle nose pliers or nimble fingers to remove the CD.

If you can't get it out - take it in for service. Unless you work on these regularly, you don't know which model superdrive is in your Mac and how hard, deep, gentle you can be with tools to help dislodge the CD. Also, if you are comfortable popping the back off your Mac - you could use iFixit to get to the drive itself and the CD will likely fall out once you have that component out of the Mac and away from the felt skirt.

Again, have a good firm grip - if you are so nervous that your palms are sweaty, that's your signal to see about getting a technician to help or waiting a bit to convince yourself you can shake it loose. These computers are made to endure UPS and FedEx shipping, packing in luggage in a bumpy car and your shaking should be on that level of violence and no more. If it's lodged behind the eject mechanism, you'll need someone to get inside and clear things in most cases.

Comment: A little shake and enough of it stuck out to grab. Nice!

Comment: Unless someone wedges it in, that's the usual manner of things. I went overboard since others may need the lengthy explanation.

Comment: Shut it down and shake it works!

Comment: I had no idea it could be so simple.  The disc popped right out on the first try.

Comment: Really thanks for the solution. It really doesn't make sense but it works... thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Thankfully I haven't had to deal with this, but I did find a [few suggestions](http://www.pcworld.com/article/170555/remove_cd.html) on how to deal with this:

- Use gravity. Tilt the MBP (you'll probably want it turned off) and see if you can slide it out.
- Try to force-eject it by holding down the mouse button as it boots. Possibly combined with tilting it. I don't have great faith in this one (I believe discs are ingested/ejected using some sort of bands at the side, so they may not be able to make contact with the disc).
- Try a business card or other thin but stiff object with some sticky tape to try and grab the disk. With this one you'll obviously want to make sure the tape is securely attached to your grabber object so that it doesn't come off inside your drive, making things worse.

Comment: +1 for the sticky tape on postcard idea. I got a mini CD out of an iMac this way. Had a certain feeling of risk though.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking the back cover off the Macbook exposing the RAM, HDD, and Optical drive. Then unplug the battery. Then remove the three screws securing the Superdrive in. Slide the superdrive out and disconnect the Sata wire connecting the Superdrive to the logic board.

After the superdrive is removed, either try to slide the mini-disk out using different tools or tweezers. If you cannot get it out that way. Take apart the optical drive until you can access where the disk is stuck. Take out the disk, then reassemble the optical drive and the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mnh7TQUsTg

Or do this:

Just power off and holding the MBP upside down just shake it in a vertical motion. The mini cd should pop out.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: Power OFF first. Hold Mac in a vertical position with CD Drive positioned South, knock it on your lap moderately as necessary. The cd will just come out.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend hitting a laptop. Especially one that contains a traditional hard disc with spinning platters. Of course, having the machine switched off gives a lot of protection to the disk by keeping the heads out of the way. But hitting the thing still seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I used an expired credit card.  Wrapped sticky tape around the end, sticky side out. Secured it with more tape, smooth side out, so only the edges of the card were sticky. Slid the card in above the CD and put gentle downward pressure on it as I withdrew the card.  The CD rolled out.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to extract the CD by fishing around the slot gently with a business card (scotch tape affixed). Thanks a ton for the advice!

Answer (score -2):

if you can see edge of mini CD ,try putting standard size CD on top of this mini CD and push it as much as it goes inside and then pull it out it will take both CDs out.

Answer (score -2):

Using two cards to pull it gently works

Comment: I've seen many cases where people bring in computers for support with several cards in stuck with the drive. I'd caution anyone putting things in to lever out stuck drives. Often something substantial enough to help won't fit or isn't long enough to matter.